# How to compile C to raw binary in OSX?

Tags: c, macos, operating-system, freestanding

Im following a tutorial on how to create an OS from scratch. I'm at the point where I need to start writing code in C but I need to compile it, in free standing mode, to raw binary. The commands given are:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel.o --oformat binary
```

The first command works, the second doesn't. OSX's linker doesn't know anything about -Ttext. Anyone know a way around this without using a virtual linux system? There must be a way.

objcopy doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there must be a way.  Apple doesn't encourage such things.  Where are you planning to run this program?  Have you considered whether the GNU BinUtils can be compiled on/for macOS (Mac OS X)?  I've not tried it recently; I don't recall whether I tried it in times past or not.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into it

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the GNU utils using homebrew and that came with gobjcopy which I used. I got the download information from here:
https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

I just pasted all the installatoin commands into a .sh file and ran it.

The commands I ended up using after installing were:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
gobjcopy -O binary kernel.o kernel.bin
```